# Logging into a server using JSON object

Tags: android, json, http, object

I've a bit of code that will be used to login to a clients `server` with his user name and password. Here is the code that I am using. My problem is that it isn't authenticating properly. I've checked the `URL`, user name & password but still there seems to be some sorta error

```
public class HttpClient {

private static final String TAG = "&&----HTTPClient-----**";
public static void SendHttpPost (String URL, JSONObject jsonObjSend){

    try{    
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost(URL);
            Log.v("The url is","The url is "+URL);

            StringEntity se;
            se = new StringEntity(jsonObjSend.toString());

            httpPostRequest.setEntity(se);
            httpPostRequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPostRequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
            HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpPostRequest);
            Log.i(TAG, "HTTPRESPONSE RECIEVED" +(System.currentTimeMillis()-t) + "ms");
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if(entity != null){
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                String resultString = convertStreamToString(instream);
                Log.v(TAG , "The response is " +resultString);
                instream.close();
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(resultString);
                JSONObject sessionJson = jsonObj.getJSONObject("session");
                String sessionId = sessionJson.getString("sessionid");
                String name = sessionJson.getString("name");
                Log.v("The name is"+name,""+sessionId);
            }
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try{
        while((line = reader.readLine()) !=null ){
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally{
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
```

}
}

This is the HOMEACTIVITY

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String tag = "##-----HomeActivity-----&&";
    private static final String URL = "**************************";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        JSONObject jsonObjSend = new JSONObject();

        try {
               JSONObject header = new JSONObject();
               header.put("username","125"); 
               header.put("password","1");
               header.put("company", "1000");
               jsonObjSend.put("user", header);

               // Output the JSON object we're sending to Logcat:
               Log.i(tag,"Output the JSON object we're sending to Logcat: " +jsonObjSend.toString(2));

              } catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
              }


    }
}
```

At the URL of home activity I am passing the actual server URL (which cannot be shared).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not calling the httppost in homeactivity

try this

```
HttpClient.SendHttpPost(URL, jsonObjSend);
```